# SQL Query to separate the comma separate the value to separate row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table as below.

Input

```
         + -------------------------------------+
         |   Country                | Code      |
         +--------------------------+-----------+
         | India,srilanka,Australia |  I,S,A    |
         +--------------------------+-----------+
```

I need a SQL query to select the value as following format in Oracle:

Output

```
    +-----------------+------+
    |  Country        | Code |
    +-----------------+------+
    | India           |   I  |
    | Srilanka        |   S  |
    | Australia       |   A  |
    +-----------------+------+
```

Comment: There isn't an existing function, you will need to create one

Comment: It's a good idea to get rid of that horrible table and create a new one with one row per country. (This is what you want to do, correct?) This may be easiest achieved by using some programming language (PL/SQL, C#, Java, PHP, ...):  select the row from the table, scan it to build insert strings and insert the new records in the new table.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.